How can I batch compare a directory of files to their copies in a different directory?
I copied the files of an entire hard drive to a separate folder, so the contents of the drive and the folder are identical. However, the transfer was interrupted a few times, so I would like to find a way to binary compare the two directories. I am using Windows 10, so I was considering using the fc command to do this (using binary mode), but am unable to figure out how to make this a batch process to process every file in the source/destination directory.

Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].
